# Laptop doesn't hibernate when battery level is critical

Tags: power-management, 19.10, hibernate

So I finally managed to get hibernation to work.

I followed [these](https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2018/07/14/configuring-lubuntu-18-04-to-enable-hibernation-using-a-swap-file/) instructions, then added the button in gnome using 'Hibernate status button' extension. Hibernation works both when I click the button from the power menu in Ubuntu, and when I run `sudo systemctl hibernate`.

Before I enabled hibernation, when the battery level reached the critical level, my laptop would 'try to go to sleep' and then wake after a second or so, with the battery still critical.

I then followed [these](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/07/change-battery-critical-low-action-ubuntu-18-04/) instructions, and selected 'hibernate' option in the 'critical-battery-action' configuration entry. I waited for my battery to drain, but to my amazement, the laptop didn't go to hibernation mode, but just 'tried to go to sleep' like before and failed.

Is there any way to fix this, for example by binding a command to critical battery event or something?